# JAXB - unmarshall xml with dynamic tag names

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using JAXB to unmarshall elements with varying/dynamic names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835075/using-jaxb-to-unmarshall-elements-with-varying-dynamic-names)

i've been searching with no success. I want to unmarshall using JAXB something like this :

```
<root>
  <entity>
     <item_1>
           <name>name 1</name>
     </item_1>
     <item_2>
           <name>name 2</name>
     </item_2>
     <item_3>
           <name>name 3</name>
     </item_3>
  </entity>
</root>
```

, my models :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "entity")
    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Item> items;

    // setters/getters...
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // setters/getters...
}
```

but this return always empty items list. Don't know What i'm missing.

thx

Comment: You might be able to do it by using a `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` to convert between the JAXB native way of doing this (`List<Element>`) and the form you want (`List<Item>`).