# Dynamically creating labels from children elements

Tags: java, jaxb, javafx

I am utilizing JAXB to generate and read my XML document. I then use JavaFX to display these elements.  Is there some way when reading each child element and for each unique element add it to a string array list. This list will be used to generate labels inside javafx.  I will provide an example to clarify.

```
<ENTITY name="WORKORDER">
        <INDEXES>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_1">WORKORDERID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_2">WONUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_3">ASSETNUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_4">LOCATION, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="Test123">l</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="Test"></INDEX>
        </INDEXES>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN uniquekey="Y" autokeyprefix="LOCAL" autokey="Y" parentkeycol="">WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN autokeyprefix="OFFLN" displaykey="Y" autokey="Y">WONUM
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PARENTID</COLUMN>
        <INIT_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
```

So entity is my parent node. I want to be able when I see an INDEXES , COLUMNS, or INIT_ACTION element to add it into a string array or some kind of collection.  There are multiple Entity nodes this is just a small example.

My first initial thought was to inside my entity class is to create a public arraylist with all of the unique elements hard coded into the list. But I am looking for something more dynamic.

Comment: What does the JAXB generate? Is it a data model equivalent to ENTITY?

Comment: @Uluk BiY JAXB generates everything fine. I can read and write. What I was looking for is a dynamic way when discovering a child element in entity save the name of that child element inside a list.  So I would have a list specifically containing "INDEXES", "COLUMNS" "INIT_ACTION". That way I can build my gui without relying on what exactly is inside ENTITY.  If I were to modify ENTITY and add another child element. Then it would be added to the list and my gui display that extra element.

Comment: @Uluk Biy So when if I were to midify ENTITY and add something like DELTA_ACTION. It would be appended into the list automatically without me adding explicitly coding it into the list.

Comment: Hi @Derek, this question is fully a JAXB one. Use [this search entry](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjaxb%5D+title%3Adynamic+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) for the related questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835075/using-jaxb-to-unmarshall-elements-with-varying-dynamic-names seems to be promising.